# Result window open but not shown in Label and textbox in Login page program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create Login page in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) with the code:

```
try:
    # for Python2
    from Tkinter import *  ## notice capitalized T in Tkinter
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    from tkinter import * 
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk #this is how we import for Python 3.


class Main():
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("Login")

        self.page = StringVar()
        self.loginName = StringVar()
        self.loginPass = StringVar()

        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        Label(self.parent,textvariable=self.page,font=("",20))
        frame1= Frame(self.parent)
        Label(frame1,text="user name").grid(sticky=W)
        Entry(frame1,textvariable=self.loginName).grid(row=0,column=1,pady=10,padx=10)
        Label(frame1,text = "Password").grid(sticky=W)
        Entry(frame1, textvariable=self.loginPass).grid(row=1, column=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

But when I execute the above code I got only:

[image]

Label and text box does not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the Label widget and Entry widget into `frame1` but you forgot to grid `frame1`.
Just add this after you assign `frame1` to the label widget.

```
frame1.grid()
```